# Why can't I set the user id?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have this in one of my routes.

```
var order = _this.store.createRecord('order');
order.set('product', product);

this.store.find('userProfile', 1).then(function(user) {
  console.log(user.get('id'));
  order.set('user', user);
});

order.save().then(function() {
  _this.transitionTo('products.index');
});
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Error: The backend rejected the commit because it was invalid: {userId: can't be blank}
```

And the API payload looks like:

```
{"order":{"user_id":null,"product_id":"30"}}
```

It's strange because `console.log(user.get('id'));` gets the id of the user, which indicates the `user` should be the right object.

I seems that the user id is not being set. Which means `order.set('user', user);` is not executing correclty...

My `Order` model looks like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user:    DS.belongsTo('userProfile'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
});
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you using ActiveModel Adapters?

Comment: Yep, ActiveModelAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `this.store.find` is asynchronous and returns a promise. This code is calling `order.save()` immediately after `find`, so the promise has not yet resolved, and the user record is still `null`. This is why there is no `user_id` in the payload.

The `console.log` is inside the `then` handler, which gets executed once the promise has been fulfilled, so you can access the attributes of the user. Make sure that any code that requires the `user` object happens inside the `then` handler.

```
this.store.find('userProfile', 1).then(function(user) {
  order.set('user', user);
  order.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the code isn't executed in the order which you see on screen. `this.store.find()` means: Start a background thread which should start when the search results come in.

So basically, you start a couple of things that happen in parallel and you can't know whether `find()` or `save()` execute first. I suggest to add a `console.log()` in `save()` so you can see that it actually runs before the code in `find()` (at least sometimes).

The solution is to move the `save()` inside of the callback for `find()`:

```
this.store.find('userProfile', 1).then(function(user) {
  console.log(user.get('id'));
  order.set('user', user);

  order.save().then(function() {
    _this.transitionTo('products.index');
  });
});
```

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292597/34088